# Replace "Add to Cart" button with an "Enquire" button linking to the "Contact Us" page

Tags: magento-1.8, addtocart, contact-us

In both product listings (e.g. the category page) and the product view page, I need to replace the button "Add to Cart" with an "enquire" button which links to the "Contact Us" page.

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: These two points are confusing,
one way you are saying enquire should work as add to cart and in the second one enquire to redirect to contact us page?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your reply. NO, Enquiry should not work as ADD TO CART. it should link to contact us page. Let me know if you have any queries? hope it's clear now.

Comment: Ok, It means no add to cart button just enquir button?

Comment: just enquire button, you are right. that enquire button should link to contact us page.

Comment: I rewrote your question so it's more clear what you want to do. Please clarify in the comments if I didn't understand you correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the file `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`.
Change this:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

to this

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Enquire') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Enquire') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot , how to link that enquire to contact us page in both catalog and product view page.

Comment: I just explained this. See the code. I replaced the url also.

Comment: Hi,



Thanks a lot for your reply. It's worked fine, How to get same result from

Product view page.?

Comment: Use template path hints and see what file you need to modify: http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think i have to edit view.phtml or addtocart.phtml but I don't know to what code to edit, can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to remove the qty box and replace the onlick event on the button with `setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts') ?>')`

Comment: This is what i did in addtocart.phtml , but it's not working. <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts') ?>')><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>

Comment: Can you please help me, where i have to replace the code setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts') ?>') to get same result in product view page also.

Comment: Instead of `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` in `addtocart.phtml`